# Exposing html file to express.static middleware on Replit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, replit

On Replit, rendering the html file using `res.sendFile` inside a `app.get` works perfectly fine, AND I am able to add logos, styles, and js logic file by passing in `express.static` middleware.
BUT when I try to also include the html as a static file passed to `express.static` middleware, the page does not render.

Here's the replit: https://replit.com/@yanichik/NodeJSandExpressFullCourseFCC#02-express-tutorial/app.js

Renders as expected when html passed in with `res.sendFile`:

> const express = require('express'); const path = require('path');
>
> const app = express();
>
> // setup static & middleware // static -> file that server does NOT
> have to change app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,
> './public')))
>
> app.get('/', (req, res) => {   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,
> './navbar-app/index.html')) })
>
> app.all('*', (req, res) => {   res.status(404).send('Resource not
> found.') })
>
> app.listen(5000, () => {   console.log('Server listening on port
> 5000...') })
>
> module.exports = app;

[image]

Now, DOES NOT render as expected when html passed in with `express.static` middleware:

> const express = require('express'); const path = require('path');
>
> const app = express();
>
> // setup static & middleware // static -> file that server does NOT
> have to change app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,
> './public')))
>
> // app.get('/', (req, res) => { //
> res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './navbar-app/index.html')) // })
>
> app.all('*', (req, res) => {   res.status(404).send('Resource not
> found.') })
>
> app.listen(5000, () => {   console.log('Server listening on port
> 5000...') })
>
> module.exports = app;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically request for the statically exposed files like so:

https://baseURL.com/navbar-app/index.html

When you comment out get routes.

If you have your get route uncomented route then

https://baseurl.com

Will return the html file

Comment: Sanket, that's not really working. Still getting the same thing. Exposing the public folder to capture static files does work for me for capturing the non-html files (css, js, and svg) and you can see it works, but it doesn't work for the html file. And it should work the same way. I am following along this course (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oe421EPjeBE at time 5:15) and really doing the same thing but it doesn't seem to work in Replit, so not sure if there is something different that needs to be done in Replit.